# On null input "implode(): Invalid arguments passed" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, implode

I am using laravel 5.5
I have a multi-select dropdown. if I don't select any value it generates an error. **"implode(): Invalid arguments passed"**

```
<select  multiple="multiple" name="language[]">
@foreach($language_data as $language)
   <option value="{{$language->language_id}}">{{$language->language_name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Controller

```
  $language = $request->input('language');
  $language = implode(',', $language);
 DB::table('language')->insert(['language' => $language,]);
```

Comment: I am assuming that your question is how to prevent this error when the user did not select anything. You can use `isset()` and check whether the user has selected any value in the drop-down or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use a simple if:

```
if($request->input('language') !== ''){
  $language = $request->input('language');
  $language = implode(',', $language);
 DB::table('language')->insert(['language' => $language,]);
}
```

And you can have a fall back if needed to define a language in the backend if none is selected like below

```
$request->input('language') !== '' ? $language = $request->input('language') : $language = 'en_GB';

$language = implode(',', $language);
DB::table('language')->insert(['language' => $language,]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, should solve the issue

```
$language = ''; //set default language here
if($request->input('language')) {
   $language = $request->input('language');
   $language = implode(',', $language);
}
DB::table('language')->insert(['language' => $language,]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just perform a check before implode.

```
  $language = $request->input('language');
  if (!empty($language)) {
     $language = implode(',', $language);
  } else {
     $language = '';
  }
  DB::table('language')->insert(['language' => $language]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$language = optional(collect($request->input('language')))->implode(',');

DB::table('language')->insert(['language' => $language]);
```

Make a collection from the $request values, wrap in optional in the event 'language' is not a required attribute, implode the result.